# Use of COUNT twice in PHP MySQL Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following COUNT functionality working successfully in this query.  I'd like to issue the exact same COUNT/Left Join functionality on another table (same format) called HTG_ScheduledActual

This works:

```
$query_WADAHTG_TechProps =  "SELECT
        HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber, HTG_TechProps.EmpFirstName, HTG_TechProps.EmpLastName,  HTG_TechProps.Veh_Number,
        COUNT(HTG_ScheduleRequest.ID) AS current_job FROM HTG_TechProps
 LEFT JOIN HTG_ScheduleRequest ON HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber = HTG_ScheduleRequest.SSR 
    AND (HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateOriginal = CURDATE() 
    OR HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE() 
    OR HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateExact = CURDATE() ) GROUP BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber 
    ORDER BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber ASC 
    ";
```

I try to insert a second COUNT using AND and it breaks the query.  I have bad feeling I can't issue two COUNT in the same query?  How is the best way to overcome this?

```
$query_WADAHTG_TechProps =  "SELECT
        HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber, HTG_TechProps.EmpFirstName, HTG_TechProps.EmpLastName,  HTG_TechProps.Veh_Number,
        COUNT(HTG_ScheduleRequest.ID) AS current_job FROM HTG_TechProps
 LEFT JOIN HTG_ScheduleRequest ON HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber = HTG_ScheduleRequest.SSR 
    AND (HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateOriginal = CURDATE() 
    OR HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE() 
    OR HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateExact = CURDATE() ) GROUP BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber
        AND COUNT(HTG_ScheduleActual.ID) AS actual_job FROM HTG_TechProps
 LEFT JOIN HTG_ScheduleActual ON HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber = HTG_ScheduleActual.SSR 
    AND (HTG_ScheduleActual.ScheduleDateOriginal = CURDATE() 
    OR HTG_ScheduleActual.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE() 
    OR HTG_ScheduleActual.ScheduleDateExact = CURDATE() ) GROUP BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber  
    ORDER BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber ASC 
    ";
```

Comment: breaks the query **HOW**? sharing the actual error message would save everyone a huge amount of time playing 20 questions with you. And no, you can have as many count() calls in a query as you want.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS total_job

Comment: doesn't help much, since "total_job" doesn't appear anywhere in your second query.

Comment: Are you trying to reference a COUNT() outside of the select list? I get that impression because of the way you also mentioned using AND.

Comment: You have some mixed up query there. You have a GROUP BY randomly in the middle of the joins. Can you post your table declares and what you are trying to do.